# Search and replace the pattern [digits:digits] in vim

Tags: regex, vim

How do I search and replace patterns like `[4:5] [23:1] [1:22]` etc in my file using search and replace and regex . In vim when I just do a search `/[d\+\:\d\+]` the pattern is highlighted but when I use `%s/[d\+\:\d\+]/ /gc` it says trailing characters.

Answer (score 2):

though you answered your own question, I don't think that answer is correct.

your answer: `/[d\+\:\d\+]`

this won't match `[23:1]` pattern, you have to escape the `[` also, the `d\+` is not correct, it should be `\d\+`

this will replace all those matches with space: (this will replace the `[ and ]` as well)

```
:%s/\[\d\+:\d\+]/ /g
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I figured it out this is the way

```
:%s/\[\(\d\+\:\d\+\)\]/ /gc
```

Comment: @Kent, this is directed towards kartik

Comment: @all I had posted the wrong code earlier this one is the correct one.